Citation hyperlink color different based on citation key
I'm writing my PhD thesis and I've managed to include in it both a bibliography and my list of publications using biber and biblatex. I thought it would be interesting to highlight when one of my publications is cited along the thesis by coloring the \cite{...} number differently for them. For example I would like the output for \cite{Amariti:2023hev} to be orange rather than green.
The basic setup of the thesis is as follows
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{newred}{rgb}{0.8, 0.0, 0.0}
\definecolor{ao}{rgb}{0.0, 0.5, 0.0}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks = true,
    linkcolor= newred,
    citecolor= ao,
    linktoc=page
} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}

\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex, overwrite]{
    \map{
      \perdatasource{bib1.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, }, appendstrict]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=one, append]
    }
    \map{
      \perdatasource{bib2.bib}
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={, }, appendstrict]
      \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue=two, append]
    }
  }
}

\begin{filecontents}{bib1.bib}
@article{Amariti:2023hev,
    author = "Amariti, Antonio and Morgante, Davide and Pasternak, Antoine and Rota, Simone and Tatitscheff, Valdo",
    title = "{One-form symmetries in $\mathcal{N} = 3$ S-folds}",
    eprint = "2303.07299",
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    primaryClass = "hep-th",
    doi = "10.21468/SciPostPhys.15.4.132",
    journal = "SciPost Phys.",
    volume = "15",
    number = "4",
    pages = "132",
    year = "2023"
}
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bib2.bib}
@article{Gaiotto:2012xa,
    author = "Gaiotto, Davide and Rastelli, Leonardo and Razamat, Shlomo S.",
    title = "{Bootstrapping the superconformal index with surface defects}",
    eprint = "1207.3577",
    archivePrefix = "arXiv",
    primaryClass = "hep-th",
    doi = "10.1007/JHEP01(2013)022",
    journal = "JHEP",
    volume = "01",
    pages = "022",
    year = "2013"
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{bib1.bib}
\addbibresource{bib2.bib}

\begin{document}
I want the color of \cite{Gaiotto:2012xa} from bib2 to be the default (green) and the one of \cite{Amariti:2023hev} from bib1 to be another color like orange.

\printbibliography[title={First Bibliography}, keyword=one]
\printbibliography[title={Second Bibliography}, keyword=two]
\end{document}


Moreover I would like to not define a different \cite command just for the few citations which are scattered all over the thesis.
Would something like this be possible?

well nowadays I would recommend biblatex+biber to produce two bibliographies. They can do that without tricks. Generally, if you want help you should provide a small but complete example that can be used for a test and not expect people to collect bits and pieces from some old question.

@UlrikeFischer I changed to biblatex with biber as you suggested and is much nicer. I still would like to know is there is a way to do what I asked. I added a code snippet now! Thank you

You can use
\AtEveryCitekey{\ifkeyword{two}
     {\hypersetup{citecolor=ao}}
     {\hypersetup{citecolor=orange}}}


